# Collection view auto resizing and setup repeating background

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

I am using collection view to load data from API. Here i want to extend size of collection view height instead of scrolling inside collection view. And also need to repeat the background image according to collection view height. 
Here is the android layout and i want to develop similar to this.[Tap here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z5XDX.jpg)

import UIKit
import Nuke
import SVProgressHUD
import JSONJoy
class HomeViewController: UIViewController {

```
@IBOutlet weak var categoryCollection: UICollectionView!
@IBOutlet weak var tabbar: UITabBar!



var sectors:[Sector] = []
var timer = Timer()
var counter = 0
var selectedSector = ""
var selectedSectorName = ""
var webService = ApiService()
let plist = PlistHelper()
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    self.categoryCollection.dataSource = self
    self.categoryCollection.delegate = self
    for item in tabbar.items ?? []{
        item.image = item.image?.withRenderingMode(.alwaysOriginal)

    }
    UITabBarItem.appearance().setTitleTextAttributes([NSAttributedString.Key.foregroundColor: UIColor.white], for: .normal)
    UITabBarItem.appearance().setTitleTextAttributes([NSAttributedString.Key.foregroundColor: UIColor.black], for: .selected)
        listSectors()

    self.categoryCollection.backgroundColor = UIColor(patternImage: UIImage(named: "bg")!)

}
override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    listbanners()

}
override func viewWillDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
    self.timer.invalidate()
}
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    if(segue.identifier == "sectors"){
        let vc  = segue.destination as! SectorsViewController
        vc.sectorCode = selectedSector
        vc.sectorName = selectedSectorName
    }
}



func listSectors(){

    webService.listSectors({ (sectors, message, status) in

        if(status){
            if let resData = sectors.arrayObject {
                do{
                    for data in resData{
                        self.sectors.append(try Sector(JSONLoader(data)))

                    }

                    DispatchQueue.main.async {
                        self.categoryCollection.reloadData()

                    }

                }
                catch let error {
                    print("JSonJoyError:\(error)")
                }
            }
        }
    })
}
```

}
extension HomeViewController: UICollectionViewDelegate, UICollectionViewDataSource {

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    if(collectionView == bannerCollection){
        return banners.count
    }
    else {
        return sectors.count
    }

}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let options = ImageLoadingOptions(placeholder: UIImage(named: "bannerPlaceholder"),transition: .fadeIn(duration: 0.33))
    if(collectionView == bannerCollection){
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath) as! DataCollectionViewCell


    Nuke.loadImage(with: URL(string: banners[indexPath.row].ImageUrl ?? "")!, options: options, into:cell.img)

    return cell
    }
    else{

            let cell = categoryCollection.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "catCell", for: indexPath) as! catogeryCollectionViewCell
            Nuke.loadImage(with: URL(string: sectors[indexPath.row].ImageUrl ?? "")!, options: options, into:cell.photoImageView)


                return cell
    }
}
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    if(collectionView == categoryCollection){
        selectedSector = sectors[indexPath.row].Code ?? "FOOD"
        selectedSectorName = sectors[indexPath.row].Name ?? "FOOD"
        self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "sectors", sender: self)
    }
}
```

}

extension HomeViewController: UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout {

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, insetForSectionAt section: Int) -> UIEdgeInsets {
    return UIEdgeInsets(top: 0, left: 0, bottom: 0, right: 0)
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {
    if(collectionView == bannerCollection){
    let size = bannerCollection.frame.size

        return CGSize(width: size.width, height: size.height - 10)
    }
    else{
        let size = categoryCollection.frame.size
          print("size\(size)")
        return CGSize(width: (size.width / 2) - 8, height:120)
    }
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, minimumLineSpacingForSectionAt section: Int) -> CGFloat {
    return 30
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, minimumInteritemSpacingForSectionAt section: Int) -> CGFloat {
    return 0.0
}
```

}

Comment: Please ask it in more details and properly.

Comment: Please add some code and details. Thanks

Comment: Sorry.. I added the code. I wanted to extend the height of collection view when a new sector is added.

Comment: Ans by @neeraj joshi is right i think you can try it.

Answer (score 1):

Following steps can help you to increase your collection View height according to data.

1. Create Heightconstraint outlet.
2. After loading data in collection view with delay of 0.2 sec in main thread,
   Set Height Constraint constant = collection view content size height.

Comment: Thanks. But i get an error. "Cannot assign value of type 'CGSize' to type 'CGFloat'"

Comment: Try this after reload collectionview Please seperate lines @HaifaMunafar


CGFloat height = myCollectionView.collectionViewLayout.collectionViewContentSize.height
heightConstraint.constant = height
self.view.setNeedsLayout() Or self.view.layoutIfNeeded()

Comment: @HaifaMunafar height of content size is CGFloat itself.